# Count rows with Slick 1.0.0

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to create a query with [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/) 1.0.0 that returns a row count equivalent to the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

What I have so far is:

```
val query = for {
  row <- Table
} yield row
println(query.length)
```

This prints `scala.slick.ast.FunctionSymbol$$anon$1@6860991f`. Also, `query.length` appears to be of type `scala.slick.lifted.Column`. I cannot find a way to execute the query. All examples that I can find in the documentation and anywhere else do not operate on `Column` or are for [ScalaQuery](http://scalaquery.org/) and do not work anymore.

What can I do to execute this?

Answer (score 4):

Any of these should do the trick:

```
Query(MyTable).list.length
```

or

```
(for{mt <- MyTable} yield mt).list.length
```

or

```
(for{mt <- MyTable} yield mt.count).first
```

**Update:**

Printing the H2 database log shows this for the last query, which looks optimal:

```
 03:31:26.560 [main] DEBUG h2database - jdbc[2]
 /**/PreparedStatement prep10 = conn1.prepareStatement("select select count(1) from \"MYTABLE\" s5", 1003, 1007);
```

Comment: Well, this would create a list with the complete result set before counting. It does, of course, work, but for very large tables it is impractical, since length will be computed in O(n) complexity of both time and space.

Comment: I've added one more, but that may generate the same select statement as the one in thikonom's answer. Though it is slightly different

Comment: For your third version I get a `MySQLSyntaxErrorException`.

Comment: That's really strange. I am also using 1.0.0 and don't have problems with it.

Comment: @notan3xit I printed the log from the H2 database, and the last query results in an optimal solution.

Comment: The query I get is `select select count(1) from DUAL from 'MyTable' x2`. MySQL does not accept that. I tried adding parentheses to make the query syntactically correct (enclosing `select count(1) from DUAL`), but it does not yield a meaningful result.

Answer (score 4):

Although I wasn't able to check the resulting sql, you could get shorter source by dropping .list:

```
Query(MyTable.length).first
```

Comment: This looks like the cleanest solution to me, but it still seems to generate SQL that counts all fields in `MyTable` and isn't quite as efficient as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "MyTable";`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
val query = for(row <- Table) yield row 
println(Query(query.count).first)
```

The `count` is equivalent to "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table".
In order to get the first and only row you have to use `first` to get the count.

Comment: Just a quick note: `count` is deprecated in favour of `length`.

Comment: Do have any idea on what do do with values of type `scala.slick.lifted.Column` that are returned by methods like `length`? Your solution does work, but generates quite a lengthy statement with three `SELECT`s. This seems an awful lot for a simple count without any further requirements: `select x2.x3 from (select count(1) as x3 from (select x4.'id', x4.'value' from 'table' x4) x5) x2`